# How to grab a link from an anchor tag using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a click event where when user clicks on an image, they go to the product detail page. I have this:

`var $randomCartItemName = $($randomCartItem).find(".cart__item__name").html();`

which, when console.log, gives me:

`<a href="/us/en_us/shop/a2300?skuId=061006-04&amp;addonSkuId=sku-10-year-standard-warranty">
A2300
</a>`

When I click on the div that I want to take me to that page, it takes me to
`https://www.website.com/us/en_us/<a%20href="/us/en_us/shop/a2500?skuId=061007-04&">A2500</a>`

I read some docs, tried a few different things, and didn't get too far. Any recommendations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply look for the `<a>` element in `$randomCartItemName`, retrieve the value of its `href` attribute and then redirect the browser to the URL using `window.location`:

```
var $randomCartItemName = $($randomCartItem).find(".cart__item__name");
var $link = $randomCartItemname.find('a');
var url = $link.attr('href');

window.location = url;
```

Of course, you can also chain everything at one go:

```
var $randomCartItemName = $($randomCartItem).find(".cart__item__name");
window.location = $randomCartItemName.find('a').attr('href');
```

Comment: Why not combine the CSS selectors together?: `var $link = $($randomCartItem).find(".cart__item__name a");`

Comment: @DavidKnipe OP didn't say if he is reusing `$randomCartItemName` somewhere else in the code, so... instead of overwriting that object, we can simply chain it.